# Uses of data standardization without subtracting mean

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, standardization

From what I've seen, it is common practice in Deep Reinforcement Learning to standardize certain data. By standardization, I refer to the process of subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. (Certain [Reinforcement Learning projects](https://github.com/openai/spinningup/blob/038665d62d569055401d91856abb287263096178/spinup/algos/pytorch/ppo/ppo.py#L74) refer to this as normalization, and I also encountered the term Z-standardization.) One example is the [REINFORCE algorithm example code](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/reinforcement_learning/reinforce.py#L70) from the Pytorch examples:

```
returns = (returns - returns.mean()) / (returns.std() + eps)
```

The effects are clear: scaling data to have the mean of zero and a variance of one.
However, in one project I encountered the mean subtraction being omitted. (It was long ago and therefore can not provide a link.) This is something I did not see anywhere else.

Are there cases where omitting the mean subtraction - thus only dividing by the standard deviation - is beneficial in the field of machine learning? If yes, what are those? I would be particularly interested in Deep Learning.

Comment: You're spot on that terminology is, erm, not standardized. On your question, I've seen this occasionally in mainstream statistics, yet also can't remember where, but tautologically the motive could be setting aside heteroscedasticity but keep differences in levels in view.

Comment: The raw value is its deviation from origin 0 (rather than from origin mean). Measuring any sort of deviation, including from 0, but still expressed in standard units of, say, st. dev., may make its sense.

Comment: you don't always want to standardize... some times the reward function is so simple that standardizing is just overhead... however in more complex envs, baselines are fundamental